# Could not proceed to checkout

Tags: nest-device-access

I am trying to set up my personal Google account with nest-device-access. I am following the instructions and I am trying to pay the one time $5.00 fee.

I am going to this page: ## Heading ##https://console.nest.google.com/device-access/tos and when I click on the "Continue to Payment" button I am getting an error that says "Could not proceed to payment. Try again later"

My google account is in good standing. I have one payment method active and the information is valid because I have active monthly subscriptions.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you will have better luck asking on google forum.

Comment: I just hit the same issue and found this post. Their site points here for what it's worth. Where is the google forum?

Comment: Exactly. Google support for nest device access links to stack overflow and this is the only support option listed.

Comment: Exact same issue. May be the service is down?

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed now! The service started working again. I was able to make the one time payment and I am able to proceed to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, very unhelpful error message. Quite vexing.